# OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, apache

Trying to do chmod in Django (from Apache process). However, getting the following error. How can I rig this to work?

error:

> OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: myfile

code:

```
os.chmod(myfile, 0777)
```

Comment: Does the user running python manage.py runserver have permissions to do this?

Comment: @Cheche It's apache. It must not. Wondering how to make it happen

Comment: The obvious conclusion would be that the user your process is running as does not have permission to change whatever `myfile` is the path to (assuming it's a file path, which is what it's supposed to be). Aside from that... world-everything-able is almost never the best approach; always shoot for the least possible permissions.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to check the permissions of the 'myfile' folder - seems like you're not allowed to write to it. If 'myPath' is the parent directory of 'myfile', try:

```
ls -l myPath/..
```

or

```
namei -m myPath
```

Then change the folder permissions with chown if that is the issue.